# A bad Cayley–Hamilton theorem proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A\in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F})$ and $p_{A}(x)=\det(xI-A)$ why saying that $\det(AI-A)=0$ is not valid?

Comment: This is already [debunked in Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#A_bogus_.22proof.22:_p.28A.29_.3D_det.28AIn.C2.A0.E2.88.92.C2.A0A.29_.3D_det.28A.C2.A0.E2.88.92.C2.A0A.29_.3D_0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not valid because in the expression $xI$, the hidden operation is scalar multiplication, i.e., multiplication of the identity matrix by the constant real value $x$. In the expression $AI$, the hidden operation is matrix multiply, which is in general different from scalar multiply.

There's a real subtlety here: the polynomial $p_A(x)$ is, as defined by the equation, a polynomial function of a single real variable. The CH theorem says that if you, after having computed the coefficients of that polynomial, now plug in the matrix $A$ for the variable $x$, and treat powers of $x$ as matrix powers of $A$, you get the zero matrix. Doing that plugging=in=a=matrix=where=a=real=number=should=be is a very weird operation, and so the result is quite surprising.

Comment: And this might cause a person to wonder what a "variable" is, if it is not a real number... because what could it mean to multiply a matrix by a "variable", and do linear algebra "with a variable", and so on, leaving open the possibility of "substituting" (meaning what, then!?!) a matrix for the "variable". Hilarious!

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid because Cayley Hamilton says that $p_A(A)=0$ where 0 is the zero matrix, but in your argument you have a zero scalar.